# calling javascript code from node.js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to run some javascript code from external source inside node.js server and return the results. 
inside html code I would just use

> `<script>http:\\address.of.code.com\code.js</script>`

how do I run this inside node.js get the results of this script and return it to the caller ?

I have no prior knowledge of the script I want to run and it's resides in external address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: calling pure Javascript functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454971/node-js-calling-pure-javascript-functions)

Comment: @abc123: Can `require` fetch remote files?

Comment: @abc123 yeah this is asking something a good bit different. I think in the link you posted the idea there is that the script is within the same context, so in Node's case that would normally mean the same fs.

Comment: need to run the script, not to fetch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at Node's native vm module.  So building on Nazar's example:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var request = require('request');
request('http://address.of.code.com/code.js', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           var script = vm.Script(body);
           var ctxt = {};
           script.runInNewContext(ctxt);
           console.log(ctxt);
    }
});
```

This pulls the script from it's remote address and runs it without affecting the code pulling the script.  Here are vm's docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/vm.html

Comment: @Dani thanks! Mind accepting the answer in that case?

Comment: sure, I still have an issue - b/c the scripts need to run inside a browser apparently (missing document ect...) but it's out of the scope of this question...

Comment: Oh that's probably because `window === undefined` in Node.  If you look at vm's docs, you can define a context with global variables already defined, so you can define window as `{}` and it should be fine.

Comment: If it does UI stuff, yes, but in theory, using vm's context you could completely fake a dom.  Although I could see replicating events in there becoming a big headache.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
    var request = require('request');
    request('http:\\address.of.code.com\code.js', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body) 
         }
    })
```

Best regards, Nazar Medeiros

Comment: This code get me the script but does not run it I'll try @Christian Grabowski enhancement.